# What are the command line arguments for TFS default merge tool for VS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, merge

I am trying to add a merge tool in VS (`Tools -> Options, Select Source Control -> Visual Studio Team Foundation, Click Configure User Tools`), so that I can run the diff and merge correctly from the command line. The default tool works great from the VS editor, but not the command line, unless we add these settings.

I have read a lot of good things about the new merge tool provided by VS 2012. The tool is located at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\vsDiffMerge.exe
```

But I can't seem to get the command line arguments right.

Answer (score 4):

As per the links provided by Jehan [LINK1](http://osnabrugge.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/use-visual-studio-as-your-diff-and-merging-tool-for-local-files/) and the information [LINK2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmanning/archive/2006/02/20/diff-merge-configuration-in-team-foundation-common-command-and-argument-values.aspx), the command line should be this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\vsDiffMerge.exe
%1 %2 %3 %4 /m /t
```

However in the link above I noticed a comment mentioning that for VS2012, the person had to use the below command line to get it working:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\vsDiffMerge.exe
/t /m %1 %2 %3 %3 %3 %4
```

%1 = original
%2 = modified
%3 = base
%4 = merged

P.S: I dont have VS2012 and have not tested this. So cannot vouch for the answer, please test and let me know if it doesnt work so that it will help other people looking for the answer.

Comment: I just tried both of these options in VS2010 using the VS2013 vsDiffMerge tool and the first option is the one that worked the best :

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\vsDiffMerge.exe
%1 %2 %3 %4 /m /t`

Answer (score 1):

Please check below post which explains about vsDiffMerge.exe commands.

http://roadtoalm.com/2013/10/22/use-visual-studio-as-your-diff-and-merging-tool-for-local-files/

Comment: Thanks! I saw that file but don't understand how to translate the parameters to the command line arguments to put into the VS options window. I am trying to add this merge tool so that whenever I do a tf get, the merge tool opens to merge changes.

Comment: The new merge tool provided by VS 2012. The tool is located at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\vsDiffMerge.exe